# C# implementation of Bron-Kerbosch algorithm

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I am attempting to write a C# implementation of the [Bron-Kerbosch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron-Kerbosch_algorithm) in graph theory, which is used to find cliques of maximal size in graphs.

Ideally, this algorithm would produce a list of graphs, where each of those graphs would represent a maximal clique from the initial input graph. My code is not producing the expected result, and I would appreciate some guidance to writing better code that achieves this implementation.

The graph class used in this instance is a custom class based on an adjacency-list representation of a graph.

```
public class BronKerbosch
{
    public List<Graph<Person>> Run(Graph<Person> R, Graph<Person> P, Graph<Person> X, List<Graph<Person>> maximalCliques)
    {
        // if P and X are both empty, and the size of R is greater than 1 (implies clique):
        if (!P.Nodes.Any() && !X.Nodes.Any() && R.Nodes.Count() > 1)
            // report R as a maximal clique
            maximalCliques.Add(R);

        else
        {
            // Copy P's nodes for traversal
            List<GraphNode<Person>> nodesCopy = P.Nodes.ToList();

            // For each node v in P:
            foreach (GraphNode<Person> v in nodesCopy)
            {

                // Make graph with just v
                Graph<Person> vGraph = new Graph<Person>(new NodeList<Person>());
                vGraph.AddNode(v);

                // Make graph with just v's neighbors
                Graph<Person> neighborGraph = new Graph<Person>(v.Neighbors);

                // Move v to X
                P.Remove(v.Value);

                // BronKerbosch(R U {v}, P INTERSECT N(v), X INTERSECT N(v)))
                maximalCliques = Run(R.Union(vGraph), P.Intersect(neighborGraph), X.Intersect(neighborGraph), maximalCliques);

                X = X.Union(vGraph);
            }
        }
        return maximalCliques;           
    }
}
```

Any help provided would be greatly appreciated - let me know if I can provide any additional information.

--

**UPDATE 1** One context of the inputs and outputs is a graph of three people - Person A, Person B, and Person C. Code is provided below to provide more accurate detail:

```
graphR = new Graph<Person>(new NodeList<Person>());
graphP = new Graph<Person>(new NodeList<Person>());
graphX = new Graph<Person>(new NodeList<Person>());

Person personA = new Person() {FirstName = "Person A"};
Person personB = new Person() {FirstName = "Person B"};
Person personC = new Person() {FirstName = "Person C"};

Anode = new GraphNode<Person>(personA);
Bnode = new GraphNode<Person>(personB);
Cnode = new GraphNode<Person>(personC);

graphP.AddNode(Anode);
graphP.AddNode(Bnode);
graphP.AddNode(Cnode);

graphP.AddUndirectedEdge(Anode, Bnode);
graphP.AddUndirectedEdge(Cnode, Anode);

expectedClique1 = new Graph<Person>(new NodeList<Person>());
expectedClique1.AddNode(Anode);
expectedClique1.AddNode(Bnode);
expectedClique1.AddUndirectedEdge(Anode, Bnode);

expectedClique2 = new Graph<Person>(new NodeList<Person>());
expectedClique2.AddNode(Cnode);
expectedClique2.AddNode(Anode);
expectedClique2.AddUndirectedEdge(Cnode, Anode);

maximalCliques = new List<Graph<Person>>();

bronKerbosch = new BronKerbosch();

bronKerbosch.Run(graphR, graphP, graphX, maximalCliques);
```

In this situation, I would want the output to be the two graphs expectedClique1 and expectedClique2 - however, the actual output is four graphs with only personA. Hope this helps!

--

**UPDATE 2** It appears that I have found a solution to the problem, though I am hesitant to close the case until I do some more testing to confirm that my solution is correct. Will update when I am able to confirm that my solution is adequate.

Comment: Please provide current and expected outputs along with any work you have done to pinpoint the cause of the error.

Comment: Done. "Update 1" should cover my data set and output. Let me know if any other information can be of use!

Answer (score 2):

To expand on ananthonline's comment well contained data structures such as these are perfect candidates for unit testing.  Fire up your favourite testing framework and set out your expected outputs including all your boundary conditions.

Start simple, get it green and then expand.  Formalising your expected will help you think through the algorithm and might switch on a lightbulb for you.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've been at it with a framework called Machine.Specifications from NuGet, and that was how I was able to identify the errors at first - there were problems with my union and intersection methods in the Graph class. I think my biggest problem at this stage is that I'm uncomfortable with exactly how the algorithm is operating. This is brave new territory for me, who has little experience with algorithms - much less those that are NP-complete.